# Modal transition style like in Mail app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to achieve a modal presentation effect where the presented view covers the parent view only partially as shown in the picture below.

[image]

I know I could achieve this by implementing custom transitions using `UIPresentationController`. I don't want to reinvent the wheel so before I roll on with development I would like to ask.

**Is there a build in support for this kind of transition in the APIs?**

I researched all available [Modal Presentation Styles](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIModalPresentationStyle) and it appears to me there is no support for the transition I want to make and the only way of achieving it is just to code it.

Comment: I believe this is simply a non full screen viewController presented over another VC.

Comment: I think this is one of those features Apple likes to keep as a private library. You'll be able to implement your own custom modal transition easily if you're coding on iOS 8

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this exact same issue. I went down the modal presentation styles route as well and kept hitting a wall (specifically getting it working on an iPhone rather than an iPad).

After some digging around, I was able to get it working though. Here's how I did it:

To start, we need a view controller that we will be presenting (the modal one) to set it's view's background color to transparent and set the frame of the navigation controller's view to some offset.

## ModalViewController.h

```
@import UIKit;

@class ModalViewController;

@protocol ModalViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)modalViewControllerDidCancel:(ModalViewController *)modalViewController;

@end

@interface ModalViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<ModalViewControllerDelegate> delegate;

- (instancetype)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController;
@end
```

## ModalViewController.m

```
static const CGFloat kTopOffset = 50.0f;

@implementation ModalViewController {
    UINavigationController *_navController;
}

- (instancetype)initWithRootViewController:(UIViewController *)rootViewController
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    if (self) {
        rootViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self cancelButton];
        _navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController];
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [self.view addSubview:_navController.view];

        // this is important (prevents black overlay)
        self.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CGRect bounds = self.view.bounds;
    _navController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, kTopOffset, CGRectGetWidth(bounds), CGRectGetHeight(bounds) - kTopOffset);
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)cancelButton
{
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(cancelButtonClicked:)];
}

- (void)cancelButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [_delegate modalViewControllerDidCancel:self];
}

@end
```

Next, we need to set up the presenting controller to run the following animation:

- Scale itself down
- Fade out a lil' bit
- Present the modal view controller using `presentViewController:animated:completion`

**This is what I did**

## PresentingViewController.m

```
static const CGFloat kTransitionScale = 0.9f;
static const CGFloat kTransitionAlpha = 0.6f;
static const NSTimeInterval kTransitionDuration = 0.5;

@interface PresentingViewController <ModalViewControllerDelegate>
@end

@implementation PresentingViewController
...
...

- (void)showModalViewController
{
    self.navigationController.view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    self.navigationController.view.layer.rasterizationScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    UIViewController *controller = // init some view controller
    ModalViewController *container = [[ModalViewController alloc] initWithRootViewController:controller];
    container.delegate = self;

    __weak UIViewController *weakSelf = self;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:kTransitionDuration animations:^{
        weakSelf.navigationController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(kTransitionScale, kTransitionScale);
        weakSelf.navigationController.view.alpha = kTransitionAlpha;
        [weakSelf presentViewController:container animated:YES completion:nil];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        weakSelf.navigationController.view.layer.shouldRasterize = NO;
    }];
}

#pragma mark - ModalViewControllerDelegate

- (void)modalViewControllerDidCancel:(ModalViewController *)modalViewController
{
    __weak UIViewController *weakSelf = self;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:kTransitionDuration animations:^{
        weakSelf.navigationController.view.alpha = 1;
        weakSelf.navigationController.view.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
        [weakSelf dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
    }];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure its done like this

```
let newVC = <view controller you want to display>
let nav: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: newVC)
if let currVc = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController {
    nav.transitioningDelegate = currVc
    nav.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationStyle.Custom;
    currVc.presentViewController(nav, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure this is your answer - Page sheet - as in UIModalPresentationPageSheet

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/Alerts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW3

Comment: Thanks for an answer but as I wrote in my question I tried all modal presentation styles including UIModalPresentationPageSheet and none does what I want to achieve.

Comment: Additionally, I believe this link is now broken, and no longer points to the documentation on UIModalPresentationPageSheet