# iOS - presentViewController like the image (Open iMessages app store in Messages)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

[image: Open iMessages app store in Messages Screenshot]

I want present a `UINavigationController` like the image above, I use

```
nvc.modalPresentationStyle =  UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
```

But I can't change the controller's size.

This is how I did:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
vc.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
nvc.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

nvc.view.frame = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, 20, 20);
[self presentViewController:nvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

But the present viewController is still full screen.

Comment: describe in detail what exactly do you wanta nd what do you have currently.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use `preferredContentSize` as follows:

```
nvc.modalPresentationStyle =  UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

nvc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

Like,

```
nvc.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300, 600);
```

***OR***

In Presented viewController's `viewDidLoad` method write below code:

```
self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(width, height);
```

***Edit:***

1. Select your viewController or xib and set `size` property to `Freeform`.
2. Enable user preferred explicit size in Content size in attributes inspector.

[image: img1]

For more detail refer answers here:

Comment: I try the both, but it's still full screen.

Comment: Is there some settings I missed?

Comment: Thanks, but no effect. I finally found the solution: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26994655/modal-transition-style-like-in-mail-app)